# How to get specific values from a string using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I have some values in string and i want to search some particular values out of this such as {Guides,Templates,Latest Offers,Videos} which is a drop down value coming from my db. Is there any way I can take the values which is coming from db and append it with a unique identifier say '#'. Since i am new to jQuery any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

`String`

```
[yzRraPX1N69OvdtJ0LYBB0fuLuL+aimTS8ZYThUCxuk=~Guides~sfsfsfsfs~fsfsf~sfs~Latest Offers~fsfs~fsfs~sffsfs~Templates~fsfsfs~fsdgh~dfhg~Videos~sdgs~gdsgsd~sdsgsg~RRQWC01~BfV/7wyRKKEwDahd0V1ntzAbWGDtJoySPXYony4NVMc=~QWC~RRQWC01~~~]]
```

jQuery:

```js
function fnOnSubmit() {
  var flsearchvalue = $("#fldsearch").val();
  alert("flsearchvalue" + flsearchvalue);

  var formvalue = $("#frmmain").serializeArray();
  var flag = '';

  jQuery.each(formvalue, function(i, formvalue) {
      flag = flag + (formvalue.value) + '~';
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you need to save the data in that format? Couldn't you save it structured already?

Comment: Actually these are the values of a dynamic added row and i want to pass these values on 2nd screen. So i will be splitting these values on basis of '~' and '#'.So that i can get exact corresponding values on the second screen.

Comment: I understand, is [] part of the string?

Comment: You could pass `formvalue` directly instead of building an inconvenient string. Then you should be able to get your values back with `Array.prototype.find()`

Comment: I agree, and if you need it as a string you can JSON.stringify it, and parse it when needed

Comment: Actually I am passing my formvalue only but since it contains many values which  I can not remove so i need to find the desired values and then split it based on '~' and '#'.

Comment: The String which i mentioned are the values which are passing from one screen to another so i need to search my particular values and place it corresponding to the row and column on second screen.

Comment: It would be simpler to use a known format such as JSON rather than inventing your own

Comment: Can you please provide an answer in JSON only. I will try to use it because i dont know anything about JSON.Thanks

Comment: if you know nothing about JSON then you should first find some simple tutorials to learn about it. Then you might properly understand any answers that people give. And also you might find that it isn't so hard to try it out for yourself, while you're waiting for replies.